# QVariant, Buffer Overrun

Tags: c++, qt, static-analysis

### While running static analysis tool. I'm getting Buffer Overrun

Buffer Overrun 
This code reads past the end of the buffer pointed to by the return value.
the return value evaluates to &#unnamed.dResourceImpl.cpp:170.
The code reads 16 bytes starting at the beginning of the buffer pointed to by the return value, whose capacity is 4 bytes.
The number of bytes read exceeds the number of allocated bytes.
The overrun occurs in stack memory.
The issue can occur if the highlighted code executes.

```
QVariant ResourceImpl::getProperty(QString propertyName)
{
    return ResourceBase::getProperty(propertyName);
}

// In ResourceBase   getProperty(QString propertyName)  declare
virtual QVariant getProperty(QString propertyName);
```

Comment: Is it possible to fix this warning?

Comment: what static analysis tool are you using?

Comment: codesonar tool.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ - What does `ResourceBase::getProperty()` do? What data does it operate on? The analysis tool is probably right, and supposed to help you to find the source, but if you don't provide a [mcve] **we** can't help **you**.

Comment: I'm getting data from dbus, via signals and property. when recieve signal we parse data and save data into custom property and get using  getProperty, we fetch property values whenever required.

Comment: ResourceBase is base class in which these virtual function declare and ResourceImpl are derived class in which we called get-property.